# Javascript insert element at nth index in array, insertion elements from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 Javascript arrays:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

I need to insert elements of second array into the first array every 4th or nth index of the first array, resulting in:

```
['a', '1', '2', '3', '4', 'b', '5', '6', '7', '8', 'c', '9', '10', '11', '12']
```

n needs to be a parameter, so I can move n to the 5th location, or 3rd location when needed.

Any solutions appreciated. ES6 ones would be great! Thank you in advance.

Comment: yeah, you'll want to use array splice method in some sort of loop

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: Hi Mohamed, nothing yet. I've looked at splice, concat, map, and reduce examples, but my skill level is not sufficient to solve this problem and I was not able to find a similar question.

Comment: @jonas-wilms this question is sufficiently different than the one you point to as a duplicate.

Comment: Please ping @Rajesh for that, you closed the question and can actually reopen it. He is a gold badge holder, Bob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the smaller array using `forEach` use `splice()` to insert elements.

```js
let arr1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']
let arr2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']

function insertArr(arr1,arr2,n){
  arr1 = arr1.slice();
  arr2.forEach((a,i) => {
    arr1.splice(i*n+i,0,a);
  })
  return arr1;
}

console.log(insertArr(arr1,arr2,4))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `forEach` with iterator as below:

```js
let arr1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12'];
let arr2 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

let index = 0;
arr2.forEach(function(v){
  arr1.splice(index, 0, v);
  index += 5;
});

console.log(arr1);
```

Now about the ES6, here is how I would write it:

```js
let arr1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12'];
let arr2 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

let index = 0;
Array.from(arr2).forEach((v)=>{
  arr1.splice(index, 0, v);
  index += 5;
});

console.log(arr1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
b.forEach((itm, indx) => a.splice(Math.ceil(a.length/b.length)*indx, 0, itm));
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate the 2nd array with `Array.flatMap()`, take the respective sequence from the 1st array with `Array.slice()`, and combine it with the current element using spread. Use `Array.concat()` with slice to add leftover items if any.

```js
const fn = (n, added, target) =>
  added.flatMap((el, i) => [el, ...target.slice(n * i, n * (i + 1))])
  .concat(target.slice(n * added.length))

const arr1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']
const arr2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']

console.log(JSON.stringify(fn(3, arr2, arr1)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(fn(4, arr2, arr1)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(fn(5, arr2, arr1)));
```

Comment: The first test case {console.log(JSON.stringify(fn(3, arr2, arr1)));}, truncates arr1.